# I have a problem with Flutter setting up. I can't solve "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_3_API30 was killed. "

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I can't open the emulator and I am really sad because I can't start my project.
The error says

```
"handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf cannot add library /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed added library /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib cannot add library /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed HVF error: HV_ERROR qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize HVF: Invalid argument qemu-system-x86_64: Back to HAX accelerator HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. added library /Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local"
```

AVD manager said this.
[image]

flutter doctor said there no problem.

Now I am thinking that the problem is due to the ANDROID_HOME variable thing, but I don't know how to fix it.

I would really appreciate it if you help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me when I have this problem I have just updated the ANDROID EMULATOR from Android Studio.
Sometimes the problem creates due to the AVD manager as well.
Follow these steps if upgrading of Emulator not works:-

Go to: **Tools** > **Android** > **AVD Manager**
Press the **edit** (pencil) icon next to your AVD
Change **Graphics** to **Software**.

OR

To set the ANDROID_HOME path:

To fix it go to Android Studio settings, find the proper Android SDK location, update the environment variable and restart Android Studio / your PC.

I think this will help you and your emulator works. I have got the same thing and for me it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried setting the ANDROID_HOME path and it seems it solved this problem. thank you.